# Eclipse: Maven Module missing artifact - .jar not created

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have a server project consisting of a few Maven Modules. I was now about to create another one that is supposed to contain objects that the server and any (Java) client shares. It appears that due to the Maven dependency it expects me to deliver a `.jar` file.

In my `pom.xml` I'm getting:

> `Missing artifact com.server:shared:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

How can I tell Eclipse to either create a `.jar` file and copy it where it is needed or that it should at least rely on the source code?

My project structure:

```
server (parent)
- server-data-model (maven-archetype-quickstart)
- server-web        (maven-archetype-webapp)
- server-mobile     (maven-archetype-webapp)
- server-shared     (maven-archetype-quickstart)
```

`server-web` and `server-mobile` are just providing a REST API and what I want to do is to create a `jar` file from `server-shared` for the server projects and another client project to share. It contains basically simple POJO objects (return values from the server a client is supposedto receive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project) answer:

Install the JAR into your local Maven repository as follows:

```
mvn install:install-file
-Dfile=<path-to-file>
-DgroupId=<group-id>
-DartifactId=<artifact-id>
-Dversion=<version>
-Dpackaging=<packaging>
-DgeneratePom=true

Where: <path-to-file>  the path to the file to load
<group-id>      the group that the file should be registered under
<artifact-id>   the artifact name for the file
<version>       the version of the file
<packaging>     the packaging of the file e.g. jar
```

**UPDATE**

Using maven it is very simple.

Just add the dependency in `server-web` and `server-mobile` like below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>server-shared</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you want to import other `maven` project/module or normal java project?

Comment: @StefanFalk can you provide your project structure? so that i can answer your question.

Comment: @StefanFalk Update question. so that every one can see.

Comment: @StefanFalk updated my answer check it. Hope it works for you. Do let me know if you had any problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Okay I messes up twice. This is working. :) So the problem was that this was in the **parent pom**. I should not be there because I had a circular dependency that Maven does not like as it seems.